# Navigation button is not working

Tags: java, ms-access

I have read a similar post but I still cannot get what is the problem.

I created a table in ms access, named DOCTOR, there are columns: DoctorID(number), Name(text), PhoneNumber(number), Department(text) and Specialization(text)

I connect the database to java through UCanAccess, below is the code to get connection

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Doctor 
{

    public static Connection connection; //sharing the memory

    public static Connection connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
            String db = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
            Class.forName(db);

            String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/user.oemuser/Documents/Doctor.accdb";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            return connection;
   }

}
```

In my GUI class, i have a method called getConnect to show the data from database to textfield

```
public void getConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            connection = Doctor.connect();
            statement=connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM DOCTOR";
            results = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            results.next();
            id = results.getInt("DoctorID");
            name = results.getString("DoctorName");
            phone = results.getInt("PhoneNumber");
            dept = results.getString("Department");
            spec = results.getString("Specialization");

            textField1.setText("" +id);
            textField2.setText(name);
            textField3.setText("" +nf3.format(phone));
            textField4.setText(dept);
            textField5.setText(spec);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and below is the code for the button1 which is the next button.

```
if(evt.getSource() == button1)
        {
            try
            {
                connection = Doctor.connect();
                connection.setAutoCommit(false); 
                statement=connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM DOCTOR";
                results = statement.executeQuery(sql1);


                if(results.next())
                {
                    textField1.setText("" +results.getInt("DoctorID"));
                    textField2.setText(results.getString("DoctorName"));
                    textField3.setText("" +nf3.format(results.getInt("PhoneNumber")));
                    textField4.setText(results.getString("Department"));
                    textField5.setText(results.getString("Specialization"));
                }
                else
                {
                    results.previous();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No more records");
                }
                connection.commit();
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the best component to use here is a JTable if you want to query all records within a particular database table or at the very least place the result set into an ArrayList mind you database tables can hold millions+ of records so memory consumption may be a concern. Now, I'm not saying that your specific table holds that much data (that's a lot of Doctors) but other tables might.

You can of course do what you're doing and display one record at a time but then you should really be querying your database for the same, one specific record at a time. You do this by modifying your SQL **SELECT** statement with the addition of the **WHERE** clause statement and playing off the **ID** for each database table record, something like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM DOCTOR WHERE DoctorID = " + number + ";";
```

But then again we need to keep in mind that, if the schema for your **DoctorID** field is set as Auto Indexed which of course allows the database to automatically place a incrementing numerical ID value into this field, the Index may not necessarily be in a uniform sequential order such as:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,.......
```

instead it could possibly be in this order:

```
1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 16, 17,....
```

This sort of thing happens in MS Access Tables where a table record has been deleted. You would think that the ID slot that is deleted would be available to the next record added to the table and would therefore hold that removed ID value but that is not the case. The Auto Index Increment (autonumber) simply continues to supply increasing incremental values.  There are of course ways to fix this sequencing mismatch but they are never a good idea and should truly be avoided since doing so can really mess up table relationships and other things within the database.  Bottom line, before experimenting with your database **always** make a Backup of that database first.

So, to utilize a **WHERE** clause to play against **valid** record ID's  we need to do something like this with our forward  and reverse navigation buttons:

**Your Forward (Next) Navigation Button:**

```
if(evt.getSource() == nextButton) {
    try {
        connection = Doctor.connect();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false); 

        number++;
        long max = 0, min = 0; 
        ResultSet results;
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        // Get the minimum DoctorID value within the DOCTOR table.
        String sql0 = "SELECT MIN(DoctorID) AS LowestID from DOCTOR"; 
        results = statement.executeQuery(sql0);
        while (results.next()){ min = results.getLong("LowestID"); }

        // Get the maximum DoctorID value within the DOCTOR table.
        sql0 = "SELECT MAX(DoctorID) AS HighestID from DOCTOR";
        results = statement.executeQuery(sql0);
        while (results.next()){ max = results.getLong("HighestID"); }

        if (max <= 0) { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No records found in Doctor Table."); 
            return; 
        }
        if (number > min) { previousButton.setEnabled(true); }

        if (number > max) {
            nextButton.setEnabled(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No more records"); 
            number--;
        }

        results = null;
        while (results == null) {
            String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM DOCTOR WHERE DoctorID = " + number + ";";
            results = statement.executeQuery(sql1);
            long id = 0;
            // Fill The GUI Form Fields....
            while (results.next()){
                //id = results.getLong("DoctorID");
                textField1.setText("" +results.getInt("DoctorID"));
                textField2.setText(results.getString("DoctorName"));
                textField3.setText("" + results.getString("PhoneNumber"));
                textField4.setText(results.getString("Department"));
                textField5.setText(results.getString("Specialization"));

                connection.commit();
                return;
            }
            // ----------------------------------------------------------
            if (id != number) { results = null; number++; }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ ex.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

**Your Reverse (Previous) Navigation Button:**

```
if(evt.getSource() == previousButton) {
    try {
        connection = Doctor.connect();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false); 

        number--;
        long max = 0, min = 0; 
        ResultSet results;
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        // Get the minimum DoctorID value within the DOCTOR table.
        String sql0 = "SELECT MIN(DoctorID) AS LowestID from DOCTOR";
        results = statement.executeQuery(sql0);
        while (results.next()){ min = results.getLong("LowestID"); }
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Get the maximum DoctorID value within the DOCTOR table.
        sql0 = "SELECT MAX(DoctorID) AS HighestID from DOCTOR";
        results = statement.executeQuery(sql0);
        while (results.next()){ max = results.getLong("HighestID"); }
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------            

        if (max <= 0) { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No records found in Doctor Table.");
            return;
        }

        if (number < min) { 
            previousButton.setEnabled(false); 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No more records"); 
            number++;
        }

        if (number < max) { nextButton.setEnabled(true); }

        results = null;
        while (results == null) {
            String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM DOCTOR WHERE DoctorID = " + number + ";";
            results = statement.executeQuery(sql1);
            long id = 0;
            // Fill The GUI Form Fields....
            while (results.next()){
                textField1.setText("" +results.getInt("DoctorID"));
                textField2.setText(results.getString("DoctorName"));
                textField3.setText("" + results.getString("PhoneNumber"));
                textField4.setText(results.getString("Department"));
                textField5.setText(results.getString("Specialization"));

                connection.commit();
                return;
            }
            // ----------------------------------------------------------
            if (id != number) { results = null; number--; }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ ex.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

**Things To DO...**

1. So as to remove duplicate code, create a method named
   **getMinID()** that returns a Long Integer data type. Allow this method to accept two String Arguments (***fieldName*** and
   ***tableName***).  Work the above code section used to gather the minimum DoctorID value within the DOCTOR table into the new
   **getMinID() method.  Use this new method to replace the formentioned code for both the Forward (Next) and Revese (Previous)
   buttons.
2. So as to remove duplicate code, create a method named
       **getMaxID()** that returns a Long Integer data type. Allow this method to accept two String Arguments (***fieldName*** and
       ***tableName***).  Work the above code section used to gather the maximum DoctorID value within the DOCTOR table into the new
       **getMaxID()** method.  Use this new method to replace the formentioned code for both the Forward (Next) and Revese (Previous)
       buttons.
3. So as to remove duplicate code, create a void method named
       **fillFormFields()**. Allow this method to accept two arguments, one as Connection (***connection**) and another as ResultSet
       (**results**) .  Work the above code section used to Fill The GUI
       Form Fields into the new **fillFormFields()** method.  Use this new
       method to replace the formentioned code for both the Forward (Next)
       and Revese (Previous) buttons.

**Things To Read That Might Be Helpful:**

[The SQL **WHERE** clause statement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-where-clause.htm) and the [SQL **ORDER BY** statement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sorting-results.htm) for sorting your result set.
[Searching For Records](http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/outer-join/index.html)